# After updating the WordPress getting a syntax error in the console

Tags: plugins, javascript, errors

I have updated the WordPress 5.8 and I am getting some errors in the console.

[image].

I have 5-6 custom widgets on my website that are working on the web page but in the admin panel, I am not getting it. It showing blank

[image]

I am getting this error in the console.

[image]

Even my WPBakery plugin also not working correctly.

Does anyone know how to solve it this issue?

Comment: Do a hard refresh `ctrl + f5` (chrome), or the equivalent in your browser.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast, Yes, I tried, Cleared the cache, checked in the private browser, Getting the same issue

Comment: Does this error appear on the from as well?

Comment: @Buttered_Toast, I haven't understood your last comment. It was working perfectly. Today, I updated WordPress and I notice that widgets, WPBakery, admin panel UI all are not displaying correctly

Comment: Revert back to the previous version to see if the problem goes away, if it does, try updating again to the new version.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast , I checked in theme customized I have my widget list. Please check here https://prnt.sc/1pkorau and when I clicked on the widget then I am getting https://prnt.sc/1pktife

Answer (score 1):

The second line in your screenshot, the first Red line, is showing a typo in a Javascript file called common.min.js.

If you have a plugin that minifies your javascript (Typically a cache or optimisation plugin) on your site, try turning that off.

Failing that, try swapping to the default theme, then if you're still seeing the issue, turn off plugins one by one until the problem disappears.

When you have found the issue, contact the theme or plugin developers and report the issue. They will hopefully provide a fix.

Comment: But that's core WordPress isn't it? wp-admin/js/common.min.js.

Comment: It doesn't show the path, that filename could be used in any of the plugins or themes. Or, if it is core, a minifying tool is trashing the JS compile. REALLY unlikely there is a typo in core - we would all know about it.